# How to version a Sails JS Project?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, versioning

I'm trying to do versioning for my app.

Currently, my folder structure looks like this

`controllers
 ->v1
models
 -> v1`

route eg: /v1/user/testing : v1/UserController.testing

Now, I'm planning to move it to
`controllers
 -> v1
 -> v2
models
 -> v1
 -> v2`

Now both the v1 and v2 models have files that have same name. When I use two routes
`/v1/user/testing : v1/UserController.testing
/v2/user/testing : v2/UserController.testing`

Both of these point to the second one.

How can I use both the files using the same name and point to respective versions using the routes?

Or is there a better way to do it without renaming the files?

Comment: What version of sails are you using?  0.10+ should support exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: It will work for controllers but not for models. If you have two models with the same name in /models/** one will take precedence on the other regardless of the directories.